# Control pivot chart filter by combobox control or cell value without using macro

Tags: excel, combobox

I want to control the pivot chart filter by simply using combobox form control without using any type of macro.

Here is a screenshot : [image]

In the above screenshot. I have a combobox containing Name later on I will populate this combobox with the distinct name. My concern is how I can  control the pivot chart filter by changing the combobox selection.

**FYI**

datarange of pivot chart is `full name and status column`.

Report Filter is `name` column.

Axis Fields(Category) and Values are column `Status`

**Note:** I don't want to use macro for this.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: why you just don't filter using the standard pivot chart *FILTERS*?

Comment: I will show this graph to users and 80 % of the user don't know about filtering things from pivot chart FILTERS. So I am giving a dropdown which is very known to users.

Comment: not sure how you imagine that dropdowns work without a macro... how did you insert it in the first place - using 'Developer' toolbar perhaps? you could write an add-in instead of just VBA, but that's hardly a simpler solution..

Comment: Problem with macro is user has to click on enable macro to see the changes, which i don't want. If user will disable macro then it will be not be visible.